# Combining Excel Spreadsheets

Tags: excel

I have two Excel spreadsheets about institutions.

In the first spreadsheet, there is one row per institution, and there are two columns per institution. The first column is the name of the institution, the second column is the institution's username.

The second Excel spreadsheet that has two columns per institution, but variable rows per institution, depending on how many IP addresses it has. The columns are the name of the institution, and the IP address of the institution. However, as institutions usually have more than one IP, and there is a row for every IP. If an institution is Harvard University, and it has two IP addresses (for example, 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2) then Harvard will have two rows: one row for the first IP and another row for the second IP.

How can I combine the two spreadsheets, using either the Excel-provided options or with code? I have access to both MS Excel 2010 (Windows) and MS Excel for Mac 2011.

Comment: I find it hard to see which context the question has. Do you need a programming way to do that? If so, which languages? If not, then this would be off topic, as this is would be a office suite user question.

Comment: I'm open to using different methods, either within the context of the Excel-provided options or using a programming method. Happy to clarify this in any way in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Vlookup

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ex6oxhW.png]

attached is the file

http://wikisend.com/download/674420/Book1.xlsx

http://wikisend.com/download/429006/Book2.xlsx